# How do I remove words from a list from a string?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to be able to remove words I have stored in a list from a string.
currently my code is as follows:

```
old_string = "BANK TRANSACTION NUM1204012 JOHN"
remove_list = ['BANK TRASACTION', 'PAYMENT TO', 'PAYMENT FROM', 'BANK FEE']
for x in range(len(remove_list)):
      new_string = old_string.replace(remove_list[x], "")
```

This method didn't change anything in the strings
The old string will also be changing every time in a different for loop, I am trying to remove the unnecessary words from bank statements in order to have them presented neater.
I want to be able to keep the number and the name, but remove the rest
I would for example like: new_string = NUM1204012 JOHN
I have also tried using regex

```
new_string = re.sub(remove_list[x], '', old_string)
```

but this method removed every instance of a character in remove_list

Comment: 1) Sort the items in the remove list by length in the descending order, 2) Remove all one by one in a loop modifying the new_string and passing new_string initialized with `old_string` before the loop. You only need a regex if you have to check for exact words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the updated sting in `new_string`. That is why the string is not changed. Replaced it with the `old_string`.

```
old_string = "BANK TRANSACTION NUM1204012 JOHN"
remove_list = ['BANK TRANSACTION', 'PAYMENT TO', 'PAYMENT FROM', 'BANK FEE']
for x in remove_list:
      old_string = old_string.replace(x, "")

print(old_string.strip())
```

**Explanation**

- Replaced the `old string` content completely.
- The last `strip` method is used to remove the spaces from the beginning and ending of the string.

**Output**

```
NUM1204012 JOHN
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm actually getting my first string from a spreadsheet using openpyxl, so I just put the string into it's own string and then put it through the loop. It's working now thx

Answer (score 0):

Going with your implementation you need to do the following

```
old_string = "BANK TRANSACTION NUM1204012 JOHN"
remove_list = ['BANK TRANSACTION', 'PAYMENT TO', 'PAYMENT FROM', 'BANK FEE']
new_string = old_string
for to_remove in remove_list:
      new_string = new_string.replace(to_remove, "")
```

But this solution is not optimal.
you have also a typo in remove_list